# What genre is 'Goodnight Julia' from Cowboy Bebop?

Tags: jazz, similar-artists, bebop

`Goodnight Julia` is a sax solo from Cowboy Bebop anime series. Cowboy Bebop has `Bebop` genre jazz songs but `Goodnight Julia` doesn't sounds like bebop to me. I want to know this kind of genre , also recommend songs similar to `Goodnight Julia` sax solo.

Here is the [link](https://youtu.be/tpGRXCp_BXA) to sax solo.

I think sax played in this song is tenor sax , I very much like the sound of tenor but cannot find songs. Please recommend songs which has some good lyrics and tenor sax.

P.S - Maybe I sound confused and complicated but I am new to Jazz.

Comment: The tenor sax solo is played by Joshua Redman

Answer (score 3):

You're right, "Goodnight Julia" is certainly not bebop!

In terms of a genre, it might be more trouble than it's worth to put a label on it, but **smooth jazz** might be the best option for this piece.

As for other tenor sax pieces, I can't recommend much with lyrics, but you might want to check out Dexter Gordon, one of the most famous jazz tenor saxophonists of all time. His solo in [Watermelon Man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbHJHPTikQA) is really famous and starts at 2:45. You really can't go wrong with Dexter Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go as far as to call it a jazz ballad. Some of my favorite jazz ballads are John Coltrane and Duke Ellington's *In a Sentimental Mood*, Ella Fitzgerald's *Round' Midnight*, the Count Basie Orchestra's *Lil' Darlin'*, and *My Foolish Heart* and *The Peacocks* as performed by Bill Evans (though he is a pianist). I'm four years late on this but hey, maybe you're still listening.